# Add additional column to Board on the Sprint level in TFS

Tags: tfs

[image]My team and I are trying out TFS Online and using the Scrum template.  Is it possible to add an additional column to the Board of the `Current Sprint`? I know you can do it at the Feature level and the Back Log level but can't seem a way to add it at the Sprint level.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is impossible on VSTS for now.** There has been a suggestion on UserVoice  and already in the plan.

> [Customize the columns on the Task Board](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3229015-customize-the-columns-on-the-task-board)
>
> We have finalized our plans how we can enable customizable columns on
>   the task board. We expect that we can **deliver this to you in the
>   next few months.**
>
> When our plans are more formalized we will give you an update.
>
> *Sandeep Chadda Program Manager* responded  ·  May 10, 2016