# How to change column name on task board on sprint level in TFS 2018?

Tags: tfs

There is similar [old thread from 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064593/add-additional-column-to-board-on-the-sprint-level-in-tfs) about add column, but there was no such functionality at that time.

My question is about TFS 2018. See the attached screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Looks like it is on the roadmap, but still not implemented: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365416/customize-the-columns-on-the-task-board.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the TFS more step than for the Azure Devops Services.

Step details for the TFS 2018:

1. Install Process Template Editor for VS 2017:

[image]

2. Start the work item editing:

[image]

3. Select your TFS collection:

[image]

4. Select the Task work item in an exiting team project:

[image]

5. Open the workflow tab of the work item edit form:

[image]

6. Add a new state and transitions:

[image]
[image]

7. Update a reason for each new transition:

[image]

8. Save your work results.
9. Open command prompt in (VS2017 Install Dir)\Common7\IDE folder. By default: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
10. Download the process configuration file for you team project:

> witadmin.exe exportprocessconfig /collection:http://tfs-srv:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:{TEAM_PROJECT_NAME} /f:{FILE_PATH}.xml

11. Add your new state to the task backlog definition:
    [image]
12. Upload your new process configuration file:

> witadmin.exe importprocessconfig /collection:http://tfs-srv:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:{TEAM_PROJECT_NAME} /f:{FILE_PATH}.xml

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nothing new in this area. If you want to get new columns you have to customize your process template and add new states to the task work item type:

For Azure DevOps Service:

1. [Create an inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process?view=azure-devops#create-an-inherited-process)
2. [Modify the workflow of a work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process?view=azure-devops#modify-the-workflow-of-a-work-item-type)
3. [Apply the customized process to your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process?view=azure-devops#apply-the-customized-process-to-your-project)

For TFS/Azure Devops Server ([On-premises XML process model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/on-premises-xml-process-model?view=azure-devops-2019&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops)):

1. [Change the workflow for a work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/change-workflow-wit?view=azure-devops-2019)

For TFS you can use [Process template editor](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiNmJa61OrgAhXtlosKHaIRBOEQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmarketplace.visualstudio.com%2Fitems%3FitemName%3DKarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor&usg=AOvVaw3qj-EaFkTp2Xj2iwTHZKul).

The Review state in the Task Work Item Type (Azure DevOps Service):

[image]

The Review state in the scrum board:

[image]

Comment: Sorry that for Azure DevOps Service for Server the same )))

Comment: Updated for TFS

Comment: I still can't find the "All processes" and the tabs "Layout", "States", "Rules" in TFS 2018. Can you help me?

Comment: By the way there is no option "Create inherited process" in TFS 2018. There are only "New team project" and "Export".

Comment: I`ve added a new answer with steps details.